# Code to find starting number in Collatz Conjecture given length infinitely looping

Tags: c++, collatz

I basically said it in the title, but I'm trying to write a program that will give me the starting integer for a minimum length. I wrote a different program that would calculate the length given the starting integer, but I'm having *a lot* of trouble reversing it, even using the previous code as a base. I put in a target length of 3, which should stop the code at x = 2, but it's not. Instead, it's looping, but I'm not sure why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char choice; //whether the program will run again

   do
   {
      int x = 1; //starting integer
      int targetK = 0; //desired minimum length
      int i = 0; //number of iterations run
      int lengthK = 0; //length of sequence

      cout << "\nEnter a required length." << endl;
      cin >> targetK;

      while (lengthK < targetK)
      {
         int lengthK = 1; //length of sequence

         do
         {
            cout << x << endl;

            if (x % 2 == 0)
            {
               x /= 2;
            }
            else
            {
               x = x * 3 + 1;
            }
            lengthK++;
         } while (x != 1);

         i++;
         x += i;
      }

      cout << x;
      cout << "\nLength of sequence before repeating: " << lengthK << endl;
      cout << "Would you like to run the function again? (Y/N)" << endl;
      cin >> choice;
   } while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');

   return 0;
}
```

The cout is simply so I know that it's working properly-- or, in this case, how I know that it's not.

Comment: You've disproven the Collatz Conjecture! Congratulations! You deserve a Fields Medal!

Comment: So, this is not all of your code. A minimal example that I can independently use to verify that indeed, it doesn't work please. :-) Or, I'll just assume that you really have disproven it. :-)

Comment: Ok, I edited it to have the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I see four problems with your code. First, you create a new local variable `lengthK` inside your while loop with the statement `int lengthK = 1;`. This variable has the same name as a variable outside your loop that you're using to test for a termination condition, but it is a different variable. Since you do nothing with the value aside from increment it inside the loop, I'm assuming this was a mistake and that you really meant to be working with the variable you declared first. This is the main cause of your infinite loop.

You can fix this by simply saying `lengthK = 1;`. Just drop the `int` and you will no longer be declaring a brand new variable with a lifetime limited to the loop and will instead be altering the value of an existing variable. I actually think it should probably be `lengthK = 0;`, but that depends a lot on other details.

The second problem I see is that you're doing `x += i;`. I'm pretty sure you just want `x = i;`, though `x += i;` might accidentally work because x is always 1 when it gets to that piece of code. `x = i;` would certainly be clearer.

The third problem is also tricky because it's hard to know exactly your intent. But I think you want a `while` loop with the test at the top and not a `do` loop for your inner loop.

The last problem is easier, and only effects the usefulness of your output, not the correctness of the algorithm. You probably want to print out `x - 1` and not `x` because the value of `x` that actually gave you a long enough Collatz chain is one less than the value x will have when it exits the loop.

I took the liberty of editing your question to tighten up your code a bit. Careful indentation is a really good habit to have, and I was pleased to see it. But excess white space is almost as bad as too little.

Here is a version of your code that I modified so that it solves your problem. I removed `endl` in most places so it would run faster.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char choice; //whether the program will run again

   do
   {
      int x = 1; //starting integer
      int targetK = 0; //desired minimum length
      int i = 0; //number of iterations run
      int lengthK = 0; //length of sequence

      cout << "\nEnter a required length." << endl;
      cin >> targetK;

      do
      {
         ++i;
         x = i;
         lengthK = 1; //length of sequence

         cout << "Testing " << x << "\n  ";
         while (x != 1)
         {
            cout << x << " -> ";

            if (x % 2 == 0)
            {
               x /= 2;
            }
            else
            {
               x = x * 3 + 1;
            }
            lengthK++;
         }
         cout << "1\n";
      } while (lengthK < targetK);

      cout << i;
      cout << "\nLength of sequence before repeating: " << lengthK << endl;
      cout << "Would you like to run the function again? (Y/N)" << endl;
      cin >> choice;
   } while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was making this to find a starting integer with a minimum length of 200, and the only other answer I had was 2^200. Technically correct, but it felt like cheating. I did eventually notice that I had redeclared the variable and fixed it, but by that point, I'd made such a mess I still couldn't get it to work. Your code is definitely neater than mine-- thank you for the tips on cleaning it up as well!